# Cannot fix table td width

Tags: html

I want to fix my TD width, I used the width="50%" but it isn't fixing, it is changing all table width, and I don't want to use css. I want to make it like this [width on line 2 and 3 for city and gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fi2e.png) ; any idea to fix only this line without changing all width table?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Table New </title>
</head>

<body>

<table align="center" border="1">

<tr>
<td> <img src="1.jpg" width="100" > </td>
<td colspan="2"> Welcome To <br> My Website </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> City : </td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="v1" checked> Beirut </td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="v1"> Paris </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Gender : </td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="v2" checked> Male </td>
<td> <input type="radio" name="v2"> Female </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Name </td>
<td> First Name : <input type="text" name="v3"> </td>
<td> Last Name : <input type="text" name="v3"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Photos </td>
<td> <input type="file" name="v4"> <br> <input type="file" name="v4"> <br> <input type="file" name="v4"> </td>
<td> <input type="submit" name="v5" value="send" style="float:right;" > </td>
</tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible by only changing those two `tr`. Here's one possible solution, adding another pseudo column on the left:

```
<table align="center" border="1">

  <tr>
    <td> <img src="1.jpg" width="100" > </td>
    <td colspan="3"> Welcome To <br> My Website </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> City : </td>
    <td width="100px"> <input type="radio" name="v1" checked> Beirut </td>
    <td colspan="2"> <input type="radio" name="v1"> Paris </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> Gender : </td>
    <td> <input type="radio" name="v2" checked> Male </td>
    <td colspan="2"> <input type="radio" name="v2"> Female </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> Name </td>
    <td colspan="2"> First Name : <input type="text" name="v3"> </td>
    <td> Last Name : <input type="text" name="v3"> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> Photos </td>
    <td colspan="2"> <input type="file" name="v4"> <br> <input type="file" name="v4"> <br> <input type="file" name="v4"> </td>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="v5" value="send" style="float:right;" > </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

However, this is a good example why it's not considered good practice to use html `table` and `colspan` - it quite soon gets rather complicated. But in this case, unless you add a lot of new rows or change the layout a lot, it probably works just fine.